# how to post data into mysql using android volley

Tags: android, mysql

Simply i want to make registration page which stored user data i did post but no data stored in database
phpfile

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phonenum = $_POST['phonenum'];
        $address = $_POST['addresstext'];
        require_once('config.php');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,email,password,phonenum,address) VALUES ('$name','$username','$email','$password','$phonenum','$address')";
        $r = mysqli_query($dp,$sql);
        if($r){
         echo "Successfully Registered";
        }
        else{
            echo "Could not register";
        }       
        mysqli_close($dp);
    }
?>
```

signup page.java

```
public class DrSignup extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://giclub.esy.es/Register.php";

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUM = "phonenum";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";

    EditText usernametext,nametext,emailtext,phonenumtext,addresstext,passwordtext;

    TextView link_login;
    ImageView profileimg;
    Button btn_signup;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drsingup);
        link_login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_login);
        profileimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimg);
        btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        usernametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        nametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        phonenumtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
        addresstext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addresstext);
        passwordtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        link_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        profileimg.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent I = new Intent(this,WelcomeActivity.class);
        if (view == link_login)
        {
            startActivity(I);
            finish();
        }
        else if (view == profileimg){
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
        else if (view == btn_signup){
            registerUser();

        }

    }

    private void registerUser()  {
        final String username = usernametext.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = passwordtext.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = emailtext.getText().toString().trim();
        final String name = nametext.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phonenum = phonenumtext.getText().toString().trim();
        final String address = addresstext.getText().toString().trim();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(DrSignup.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(DrSignup.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                params.put(KEY_NAME,name);
                params.put(KEY_ADDRESS,address);
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUM, phonenum);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            profileimg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
    }
    }
```

no thing is toasted and non error is shown in logcat
what is the problem ?

Comment: In your code why there is GET method checking when you require POST data ? `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')` change it to post , it may help

Comment: bad luck for me :D i don't know how i forgot that :D thank u ^^

Comment: but how can i add image in the same database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are not getting any response because in your server side you     are comparing request method with get but actually you are sending data to server not retrieving from it so change it like this

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phonenum = $_POST['phonenum'];
    $address = $_POST['addresstext'];
    require_once('config.php');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,email,password,phonenum,address) VALUES ('$name','$username','$email','$password','$phonenum','$address')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dp,$sql);
    if($r){
     echo "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else{
        echo "Could not register";
    }       
    mysqli_close($dp);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: but how can i add image in the same database ?

Comment: if that solved your problem please accept it as a correct answer

Comment: Use picasso or glide in android send it to server either using base64.

Comment: accepted :) ... can u help me ? i can use picasso but how to upload image in the same insert ?

Comment: go through thil you will get your answer regarding image upload https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Answer (score 1):

@Amr93 I think u are sending data in post method and in API you'r checking

"request method == GET"

Look at this

Replace this

> ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

With

> ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
```

to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
```

---

**Upload Image  :**

1. upload bitmap in your activity and encode into the String
2. on the server side declare the variable to assign the unique name to each image and also declare the path, where you want to store the image

   for eg : `$path = "uploads/$id.png";`

   `$actualpath = "http://url_path/xyz/$path`;
3. after that insert the `$actualpath` into the db

   **Note :** Don't forget to decode on the server side

Comment: right answer but how can i upload image in the same database ?

Comment: u want to upload image from the mobile to the db?

Comment: check my updated answer... if u struck any where i will provide u a guide

Answer (score 0):

You use request type "POST" in your android code

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
```

and in php code handle it using "GET" request. So code of if condition not executed

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
```

change it to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
```

it will solve your problem